# agreed to vs agreed on. Are they interchangeable?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/agree):
>
> The warring sides have **agreed on** an unconditional ceasefire.
>
> All 100 senators **agree to** a postponement.

According to the definition, **"agree to" implies "something to do"**, but they used "on" with the ceasefire example although both parties will stop shooting at each other which is an action. Also [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=agreed%20to%20this%20arrangement%2C%20agreed%20on%20this%20arrangement&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cagreed%20to%20this%20arrangement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cagreed%20on%20this%20arrangement%3B%2Cc0) suggests that it is **"agree to an arrangement"** NOT **"agree on an arrangement"** although an arrangement does not imply an action by necessary, it is more like an agreement on a contract or something.

**It gives an impression that "agree on" and "agree to" are interchangeable. Is that correct?**

Comment: Not entirely. Two sides can **agree to** stop fighting, but you can't use **agree on** with a verb.

Comment: There's usually a difference between two parties agreeing ***to** [some procedure]* and agreeing ***on*** it. Using ***to*** there implies the procedure already existed (or had at least been *defined*), which both parties agreed ***to implement / honour*** (effectively, the negotiations have been about whether or not to go ahead with some predefined course of action). On the other hand, the ***on*** version implies what they were negotiating was the ***detail*** (of ***how*** to enact the procedure; defining "the rules").